# DJIFlightControllerState - hardware timestamp

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

We need to know the hardware timestamp of when drone position and attitude updates are sent to:

`DJIFlightControllerDelegate`'s

`- (void)flightController:(DJIFlightController *_Nonnull)fc didUpdateState:(DJIFlightControllerState *_Nonnull)state;`

We've searched the docs but aren't able to determine when the drone recorded values for `DJIFlightControllerState` to the delegate.

We would like to have a canonical timestamp, on the hardware (drone), that these values were captured. We need to account for latency in the values and when they arrive via the SDK.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This delegate method will be updated once the SDK receives pushed flight controller state data from the flight controller hardware of the aircraft, SDK doesn't know and cannot determine when the data starts to push. The data push rate is **10hz**.